# Optimization parameter for classification

Tags: machine-learning, svm, optimization, discriminant-analysis, statistical-learning

I do not have enough knowledge about optimization.
My problem is simple.

Lets say I have 100 classes. Each class contains some instances (images). The feature vector obtained from a particular image depends on a parameter P.

I need to learn this parameter automatically by maximizing the classification accuracy.

As I have no idea about optimization, could you please suggest me about how I can do this.

Thank you.

Comment: please specify your classifier

Comment: Any classifier, SVM, LDA, any

Comment: I think the question is too broad. I suggest you try a specific classifier and ask specific questions about the details of optimization.

Comment: However, we can already tell you that classifier optimization is far from a simple problem. Frank Harrell will soon also tell you that accuracy (or other measures based on the proportion of successes / failures) are not a goot target value for optimization and that you need so-called proper scoring rules instead. Have a look around here, there are actually quite a few optimization questions already on this page.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to add an exra grid on top of your typical learning stack. Since you didn't specify the algorithm of choice or any properies of p, I can't really be more specific. The most basic version would look something like this though:

For all values of p:

1. Apply p to the images to obtain feature vectors
2. Apply the learning procedure using these feature vectors
3. Remember the performance for this choice

Afterwards, look at the value of p that gave you the best performance and use this for subsequent learning. Remember to use a held out part of your dataset for testing.

For more information, look at 'cross validation'.